# Hashing set of objects C#

Tags: c#, hash

I have number of orders and each order contains purchased `Item` objects.

```
1 : {Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5}  
2 : {Item2, Item8, Item4, Item3, Item11, Item5} 
3 : { ... }
```

My goal is to establish how frequent each of those items were bought together and able to get results in O(1).

My idea was iterate through orders, based on subset items - increment particular array's element. That will give me possibility extract required value in O(1).

Eg. Item3 and Item4 were bought 2 times.

`int frequency = myArray[getHash(Item3+Item4)]`

`print frequency;`

`Output : 2`

**Problem:**

Develop a `int getHash(...)` function, which will be able to hash subset of items.

**Note: {Item1, Item2} = {Item2, Item1}**

Thank you very much! Any help of better ideas are welcome!

Comment: So, if you were to ask, "How often are items 3+4+8 puchased?" from your example above, the answer would be `1` (because even though 3 and 4 appear in both, only the second list _also_ contains 8)?

Comment: This seems similar to text search. Suppose you have docs `Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5` and `Item2, Item8, Item4, Item3, Item11, Item5`, and want to search for docs where they contains both words `Item3` and `Item4`. You can use [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) for this which is incredibly fast.

Answer (score 4):

Because `{A,B} = {B,A}` You first need to sort your list before proceeding. It doesn't matter what you sort by, but you do need to ensure that no values are considered equal for sorting purposes unless they can be interchangeable in their ordering.

Next, any simple hashing algorithm should work. A common technique is to use two primes, I'll call them `c` and `p`.

```
int hash = c;
foreach(Item i in items) hash = hash * p + i.GetHashCode()
return hash;
```

`p` is sometimes chosen to be 31 because not only is it prime, but a compiler resolves it to a bitshift and a subtract, which is much faster than a multiply. `x * 31` is the same as `(x << 5) - 1` (assuming I used the proper shift... I screw that up from time to time, haha.)

Comment: Note that you don't strictly *need* to sort the items first, as there are other ways of solving the problem, but this is one way, and it's a good one.

Comment: Point well taken, Servy. There are other methods of determining the uniqueness. However, if it's going to be hashed, they have to be added to the hash in the same order. If it was reasonably possible to add things to the hash in a different order, it wouldn't make for much of a usable hash.

Comment: Your hash algorithm could be the exclusive or of the hash of each item.  That would result in the same hash for the same set of items regardless of their order.

Comment: That's true, but it would only scales up to 32 items. After that you end up with a significantly higher number of collisions. It seems like it wouldn't, but it does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `i.getHashCode()` will give different hash values of each instance of Item. E.g getHashCode(Item1) in order1 !=  getHashCode(Item1) in order 2. How do you handle that?

Comment: @corsiKa I just ran a few tests, because you'r right that seems odd.  With 100,000 collections each containing 100 items (each randomly generated hashes) I got an average of 2.9 collisions (over 10 runs), or a collision rate of .0029%.  With 300 items per set I got 2.4.  That seems suitably low to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I'm not using hash, but I tried to give it a go in a way I would do it. Just like to try to solve that kind of challenge.

```
Dictionary<Item, Dictionary<Item, Count>> combine = new Dictionary<Item, Dictionary<Item, Count>>();

foreach (Item item in Sell)
{
    Dictionary<Item, int> key;
    if (!combine.TryGetValue(item, out key))
    {
        key = new Dictionary<Item, Count>();
        combine.Add(item, key);
    }

    foreach (Item otherItem in Sell)
    {
        if (item == otherItem)
            continue;

        Count count;
        if (key.TryGetValue(otherItem, out count))
            count++;
        else
            key.Add(otherItem, new Count());
    }
}
```

That's probably very stupid, as for each item you ends up with a dictionary of all other items bought at the same time with a counter. And if you want to know if Item1 is bought at the same time as Item2 AND Item3 vs Item2 OR Item3... Bleh. Nevermind me.